# How to eliminate duplicate records based on only few columns in table and keep one and indicate that there were duplicate records corresponding to it?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

The resultset I have is like shown below:

[image: Input resultset]

And expected output is like shown below:

[image: Output resultset]

Any idea how can we achieve this with SQL in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select city, name, salary,
       (case when cnt > 1 then 'Multiple' else 'Single' end) as Indicator
from (select t.*, 
             count(*) over (partition by city, name) as cnt,
             row_number(*) over (partition by city, name order by salary) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Actually, if you want the minimum salary:

```
select city, name, min(salary),
       (case when count(*) = 1 then 'Single' else 'Multiple' end) as indicator
from t
group by city, name;
```

Comment: Thanks for help but your answer does not satisfy my requirement. 
Notice I have mentioned indicator as "Multiple" in the expected output even though row_number of that row is 1. Getting me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM tabename  WHERE  rowid in
      (SELECT city, name, salary,COUNT(*)
         FROM tabename 
        GROUP BY city, name, salary
       HAVING count(*) > 1);
```